# Expression getting length of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, expression-trees, cil

If you have an Expression of Type Array but not of a specific array type such as int[], how to I generate an expression which gets the length in a fast way without doing the whole property fetching malarkay.

E.g. in the following

```
ParameterExpression para3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int[]), "p3");
ParameterExpression para4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Array), "p4");

Type pt1 = para3.Type.GetElementType();
Type pt2 = para4.Type.GetElementType();

MethodInfo mArrayLength = Strong.Instance<Array>.Property<int>(a => a.Length).GetGetMethod();

Expression asdf5 = Expression.ArrayLength(para3);
Expression asdf6 = Expression.ArrayLength(para4);
Expression asdf7 = Expression.Call(para4, mArrayLength);
```

mArrayLength is just the get method for the Length property on type Array.

Here the expression asdf5 works since para5 is of type int[] but asdf6 **does not** because para6's type is only of type Array. asdf7 does work.

What I want is to effectively use the ldlen instruction, which only requires an Object, rather than calling a method. Is this just a limitation with the expression tree library?

You can edit the field using reflection, and you can even compile the expression! But trying to run the delegate will result in an operation could destabilize the runtime exception.

```
Array parr = new int[5];

Expression pArraylength = Expression.ArrayLength(para3);
pOperandFieldInfo.SetValue(pArraylength, para4);

Expression<Func<Array, int>> pexchanger = (Expression<Func<Array, int>>)Expression.Lambda(pArraylength, para4);
Func<Array, int> pFunc = pexchanger.Compile();
int pint = pFunc(parr);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of arrays in .NET, the mono-dimensional, zero-based (the first index is 0) arrays (`int[]` for example) that are supported directly by the IL language (and by the `Expression` class) (as a side note they are called SZ arrays), and the other arrays (multi-dimensional ones e.g. `int[5,3]` and arrays with first index different from that exist for compatibility with some languages that support them, for example the old VB), that don't have a direct support in the IL language but are supported by the compiler that uses calls to the `Array` class. They are based on two different classes that are both subclasses of `Array`. As I've written, the low-level IL instructions are only for the mono-dimensional, zero-based ones. An `Array` object could be both, so there is no support from `Expression.ArrayLength`.

You can easily see this in [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQMDMSBMCAwggN5YKVJ4oBsCYAdsAgILIA8AKgHwAUXANoBdBAEMAThLEBPAJRkKVZTADs4qbIB0AGQCmjAObAAFhkzKAvliWVcSZPSYtW+Pq00yN0+YovKqNW9tfSNTcyssSyA==):

```
public static int A1<T>(T[] array) {
    return array.Length;
}

public static int A2(Array array) {
    return array.Length;
}

.method public hidebysig static 
    int32 A1<T> (
        !!T[] 'array'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 4 (0x4)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldlen
    IL_0002: conv.i4
    IL_0003: ret
} // end of method C::A1

.method public hidebysig static 
    int32 A2 (
        class [mscorlib]System.Array 'array'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2055
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Array::get_Length()
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method C::A2
```

Just out of curiousity, using an undocumented feature (we are playing with fire here!)...

```
ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Array), "array");
var conv = Expression.New(typeof(Conv));
var init = Expression.MemberInit(conv, Expression.Bind(typeof(Conv).GetField(nameof(Conv.Array)), par));
var array = Expression.Field(init, nameof(Conv.Array2));
var length = Expression.ArrayLength(array);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Array, int>>(length, par);
var compiled = lambda.Compile();
```

where `Conv` is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Conv
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Array Array;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] Array2;
}
```

Use it like:

```
int length = compiled(new int[100]);
```

The "trick" here is that through `FieldOffest` we can cast incompatible types that have the same memory layout. All the sz arrays share the same header format (where the `Length` is contained), so we "convert" our `Array` to an `byte[]` array (note that we could have probably converted it to any other type, but there is a distinct advantage in a `byte`: it is the smallest available type, so we are sure that we can't go "out" of the array in any way).

The expression tree is something like:

```
static int GetLength(Array array)
{
    return new Conv { Array = array }.Array2.Length;
}
```

Comment: Interesting but from a cil point of view, there is only an object type (and int32, int64, F, userdefined value types and native ints). Ldlen just takes an object in CIL, no?

Comment: I suppose it would be unsafe to compile down an Expression.Arraylength when the static type of the operand is Array.

Comment: @Nick The description of [`ldlen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldlen.aspx) on msdn is very clear: *Pushes the number of elements of a zero-based, one-dimensional array onto the evaluation stack.*. If you use on other type of arrays what you obtain isn't defined. If you pass an `Array` object that in truth is a sz-array, then it will work (because casting between `Array` and `T[]` doesn't change the reference), but if the `Array` in truth is a "special" array, then bad things will happen. But it is unclear/undefined what will really happen.

Comment: xanatos thanks for your help. The spec says you can run ldlen on an object type, but correct CIL means the operand must be either a one-dimensional array or null.

Comment: @Nick In truth ldlen will work even for multidimensional arrays, returning x*y size

Comment: @Nick And the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) of the CIL language tells something different: *The ldlen instruction pushes the number of elements of array (a zero-based, one-dimensional
array) on the stack.* and *Correct CIL ensures that array is indeed always null or a zero-based, one dimensional array.*

Comment: hmm it says at the bottom "correct CIL ensures that array is indeed always null or a zero-based, one-dimensional array"? Null is not an array. Anyway your hack awesome, thanks for your help

Comment: @Nick There is no problem with that. Either the reference is null, in which case _NullReferenceException_ is appropriate, or it points to an SZ array (single-dimensional zero-based). If any other reference is allowed to appear on the stack, the CIL is not valid.

Comment: @IllidanS4 aye i don't think anyone is disagreeing here. Technically in CIL, it's just int32, int64, native ints, managed pointers, F and Objects (and user-defined value types). I was thinking about it through this lense where an array is just an object.